# Math.round(Math.random) return 3 unique numbers issue

Tags: javascript, random

Okay, so I need to return 3 random numbers that do not equal each other. Then when running the function again the numbers should also not be any of the numbers selected in the previous run.

I wrote up a function to do so, but I keep getting undefined as one of the return values.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
f1 = 0; f2 = 0; f3 = 0;

function randomNumber(r1, r2, r3) {
    ranNumb = Math.floor(Math.random()*51);
    if (ranNumb != r1 && ranNumb != r2 && ranNumb != r3) {
        return ranNumb;
    }
    else {
        randomNumber(r1, r2, r3);
    }
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#left_btn, #right_btn").click(function() {
        f1 = randomNumber(f1, f2, f3);
        f2 = randomNumber(f1, f2, f3);
        f3 = randomNumber(f1, f2, f3);
        alert(f1+" "+f2+" "+f3);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
else {
    randomNumber(r1, r2, r3);
}
```

You need to `return` the result of the recursive call to `randomNumber`.

```
else {
    return randomNumber(r1, r2, r3);
}
```

Comment: OHHHH, hahaha. I see what I did there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You missed a `return`:

```
else {
   return randomNumber(r1, r2, r3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `randomNumber`, if the number that was generated is equal to any of the three, then you call `randomNumber` again. But you forgot to *return* the result!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to tell the "else" portion of the randomnumber function to actually return randomnumber instead of just recalling it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to use a while loop, here is some code that I have adapted:

```
function generateUniqueNumbers(num_of_nums, maxrange) {
    //initialise an array
    var arr = [];
    //generate x unique numbers into an array
    while(arr.length < num_of_nums){
        //generate random number
        var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxrange)
        //initialise boolean
        var found=false;
        //loop through the array
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            //if the number exists in the array then break from the while loop
            if(arr[i] == randomnumber){found=true;break;}
        }
        //if the number is not found then add it to the array
        if(!found)arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
    }
    //if all numbers have been collected return array
    if(arr.length == num_of_nums){return arr;}
}
```

In the functions current state it may possibly return 0 as a number, as the highest range is only specified but it should do what you need :)