# Making certain randomized data is unique

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm pulling in three randomized records via an API and I would like to ensure that none of the records are the same. How can I edit my code so that it checks that the records are unique?

Here is my current code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var person1 = data.records[1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)];
            var person2 = data.records[1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)];
            var person3 = data.records[1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)];
            $(".one").html(person1.name);
            $(".two").html(person2.name);
            $(".three").html(person3.name);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("boo!");
        }
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: 1. Remember previous answers. 2. Don't duplicate them. --or-- Generate numbers 1-9, randomize them, and pick three at random.

Comment: Something like the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507109/math-roundmath-random-return-3-unique-numbers-issue

Comment: What properties make the responses unique? What do the responses look like?

Comment: the `name` attributes will all be unique.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, while that question is somewhat similar to mine, the code is highly specified for that question-asker's exact situation. My question is different enough, if not only for the fact that it has elicited an entirely new answer than the question that mccannf has pointed to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `data.records` is an array and not an object, use `splice` with a random number from 0 to `.length` to remove and return array elements without having to worry about duplicates. As follows:

```
var data = ["Gary","Fred","Seb","Garrett"];
while (data.length) {
   alert(data.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length), 1)[0]);
}
```

Fiddle: http://tinker.io/7c898

Note that this makes the assumption that the originating array is already unique.

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the names from the response like pulling numbers for the lotto...

http://jsbin.com/ulisat/3/

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...

Comment: You have a pool of records. Pull a record out of the pool destructively, then it cannot be duplicated. So, for example, use `Array.shift()` (docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

Comment: I get it now... quite similar to @Sébastien's answer but without code. Thanks though!

Comment: Exactly like his answer... Which hadn't made it to my browser when I posted. Must be a good one.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ulisat/3/